# How to copy data from cell below?

Tags: google-sheets

Envision two rows, one up top and one below it. The cell up top is blank but the one below has 9/24/12.

How can I create a function that will make the top one copy the value of the cell below it if it is empty?

P.S. I'm not great with scripts.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that cell A1 is the top row and A2 is the next row, put the following formula in cell A1.

```
=if(A2="", "New Value", A2)
```